# Was ist das korrekte Geschlecht des Wortes »Weise«?

Tags: article

Wenn ich nicht falsch liege, sah ich das Wort »Weise« bereits mit dem Artikel "der" geschrieben, da bin ich mir fast sicher. Aber in meinen Wörterbüchern wird das Wort als feminines Substantiv angeführt. Auch in einem Onlinewörterbuch - nämlich WordReference - findet man dieses Wort mit beiden Artikeln geschrieben.

Was ist dann die aktuelle Rechtschreibung?

Comment: Mache dir keine Sorgen darüber, ob dein Deutsch gut genug ist, um hier Fragen auf Deutsch zu schreiben. Die Mitglieder dieses Boards werden deinen Beitrag editieren und kleinere Fehler ausbessern. Du kannst deinen Text mit der korrigierten Version vergleichen, indem du auf "edited" unter deiner Frage klickst. Bitte schreibe weiterhin Fragen auf Deutsch!

Comment: ... [but in case you prefer writing in English that would also be perfectly o.k.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in)

Answer (score 5):

Das Wort »*Weise*« hat mehrere Bedeutungen:

- manner, way, kind, fashion

  > **Die Weise,** mit der du mich behandelst, ist untragbar!
  >   **The way** you treat me is intolerable!
- melody, tune

  > **Eine sanfte Weise** klang aus der Hütte.
  >   **A gentle melody** sounded from the hut.

In beiden oben genannten Bedeutungen ist das Wort weiblich. Im Nominativ singular heißt es also: *»**Die** Weise.«*

Aber das Wort hat eine dritte Bedeutung:

- sage

  > **Der Weise** trat aus dem Tempel heraus.
  >   **The sage** *(the wise man)* stepped out of the temple.

Aber wenn man *»**der** Weise«* sagt, legt man sich darauf fest, dass der Weise ein Mann ist. Es ist aber auch möglich, dass es sich um eine Frau handelt, dann muss es wie folgt heißen:

> **Die Weise** trat aus dem Tempel heraus.
>   **The sage** *(the wise woman)* stepped out of the temple.

---

Deutsch macht sehr regen Gebrauch von einem Mechanismus, den man *[Substantivierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung)* nennt (engl.: *[nominalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization)*). Dabei werden Verben und Adjektive wie Substantive verwendet. Im Englischen ist die Substantivierung von Adjektiven selten. Ich kenne nur das Beispiel

> the poor and the rich

In dieser Phrase sind *poor* (arm) und *rich* (reich) zwei Substantive, obwohl sie viel häufiger als Adjektive verwendet werden (*"the poor girl", "the rich man"*).

Im Deutschen werden Adjektive viel häufiger substantiviert. Dabei wird, wie im oben zitierten englischen Beispiel, ein Adjektiv, das als Attribut eines Substantivs verwendet wird, selbst zu Substantiv, wobei das ursprüngliche Substantiv weggelassen wird.

Beispiele:

> **Die neue Kollegin** kommt erst morgen → **Die Neue** kommt erst morgen.
>   **Der alte Mann** sieht traurig aus. → **Der Alte** sieht traurig aus.
>   **Die jungen Leute** machen so viel Lärm. → **Die Jungen** machen so viel Lärm.

Weil dabei aus dem Adjektiv ein Substantiv wird, und weil man im Deutschen alle Substantive mit einem großen Anfangsbuchstaben schreibt, müssen auch substantivierte Adjektive großgeschrieben werden. (Grammatisch sind diese Wörter tatsächlich Substantive.)

Das deutsche Adjektiv *weise* bedeutet auf Englisch *wise, sage, prudent, sapient*, und auch dieses Adjektiv kann, wie jedes Adjektiv, substantiviert werden:

> **Der weise Mann** sprach zu dem Wanderer. → **Der Weise** sprach zu dem Wanderer.
>   **Die weise Frau** sagte ein Unheil voraus. → **Die Weise** sagte ein Unheil voraus.

Beachte, dass sich im Fall einer solchen Substantivierung, falls sie sich auf Menschen bezieht, für den Artikel des substantivierten Wortes das biologische Geschlecht des Menschen ausschlaggebend ist; also nicht, wie sonst üblich, das grammatische!

> **Das** weise Weib verschloss das Tor.
>   Falsch: **Das** Weise verschloss das Tor.
>   Richtig: **Die** Weise verschloss das Tor.

Der Grund ist einfach: Wenn die Substantivierung bereits vollzogen ist, ist das ursprüngliche Substantiv nicht mehr vorhanden. Der Artikel bezieht sich daher auch nicht auf das ursprüngliche Substantiv, sondern im grammatikalischen Sinn bezieht er sich auf das Adjektiv, das zum Substantiv geworden ist. Dieses Adjektiv hat aber kein grammatisches Geschlecht. Daher springt hier das semantische/biologische Geschlecht ein und bestimmt den Artikel. Wenn aber so ein semantisches Geschlecht nicht vorhanden ist, kann die Substantivierung auch nicht durchgeführt werden.

Weil Kinder selten weise sind, wähle ich für das folgende Beispiel ein anderes Adjektiv:

> **Der** fröhliche Mann lacht. → **Der** Fröhliche lacht.
>   **Die** fröhliche Frau lacht. → **Die** Fröhliche lacht.
>   **Das** fröhliche Kind lacht. → <del>**Das** Fröhliche lacht.</del> Falsch!

Das Wort *»Kind«* ist sächlich. Ein bestimmtes Kind (nicht das Wort, sondern die Person) ist aber entweder männlich oder weiblich. Dieses biologische Geschlecht steckt aber nicht im Wort *»Kind«*. Auf der semantischen Ebene gibt es daher keine Information über das Geschlecht des Kindes.

Will man nun das Adjektiv in *»das fröhliche Kind«* substantivieren, gelingt das nicht, weil das grammatische Geschlecht des Wortes *Kind* irrelevant ist, und weil es in diesem Fall keine Information über das biologische Geschlecht des Kindes gibt. Nur wenn aus dem Kontext das biologische Geschlecht des Kindes klar hervorgeht, kann man entweder »der Fröhliche« oder »die Fröhliche« schrieben.

Wenn also Substantivierungen geschehen, und sie sich auf Personen beziehen, ist das Geschlecht immer weiblich oder männlich. Sächliche Substantivierungen sind möglich, beziehen sich dann aber immer auf unbelegte Dinge, oder auf abstrakte Eigenschaften.

> **Das Besondere** an dir sind deine Augen.
>   **The special thing** about you are your eyes.

Comment: Dann habe ich ein Rätsel für Dich. "Die fröhliche Person lacht." Kann man daraus "Die Fröhliche lacht." machen, obwohl auch hier das Geschlecht unbekannt ist? "Der letzte Besucher macht die Tür zu." Besucher verrät auch nichts über das Geschlecht der Person, stimmst Du zu? Wenn nein, versuch es mit "Gast". Also kann man nicht sagen "Der Letzte macht die Tür zu."? "Das neueste Parteimitglied ist sehr weise." Kann man "Das Neueste" sagen? "Das weiseste Parteimitglied ist noch neu." Dass generische Formen offen sind für das Geschlecht der Person aber die Wörter fast immer männlich, ist eine Falle

Comment: "Weise" als "Art und Weise" und als Melodie bringt Dir aber vorläufig doch ein +1 ein. Was aber ist mit dem Abstractum Weise: "Das Weise am Gedankengang Wittgensteins ist, dass ..." (wird hier nicht verraten).

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn ein Leser irgendwo, ohne weiteren Kontext, »die Fröhliche lacht« liest, kann er nicht wissen, dass der Autor »die Person« gemeint hat. Ohne weiteren Kontext hat der Leser nur den Artikel *die*, von dem ausgehend er Vermutungen anstellen kann. Wenn sonst keine Informationen mitgeliefert werden, muss der Leser also auf eine Frau oder ein Mädchen schließen, wird also männliche Personen nicht in Betracht ziehen. ...

Comment: ... Genau derselbe Effekt tritt beim dem eigentlich generischen Maskulinum auf. Mit »der Letzte macht die Tür zu« meint man in den meisten Fällen »die letzte Person macht die Tür zu«. Weil »Person« ein Nomen ist, das Menschen unabhängig vom Geschlecht bezeichnet, wird der Satz »die letzte Person macht die Tür zu« tatsächlich geschlechtsneutral verstanden. »Der Letzte macht die Tür zu« wird aber, aus genau dem Grund den ich bei »die Fröhliche« beschrieben habe, oft als Hinweis auf einen Mann verstanden. Und genau das ist der Grund für die Gender-Debatte in der deutschen Sprache. ...

Comment: ... »Das Neue ist sehr weise« ist ein unzweifelhafter Hinweis darauf, dass ein neues Ding (also keine Person) sehr weise ist.

Comment: Nein, nein. Die Sprache ist dafür viel zu flexibel. Im Deutschen lacht auch das Glück und die Sonne - natürlich benötigt man einen Kontext. Wenn der Kontext "das Mitglied" war, dann kann auch "das Fröhliche" lachen. "Wir haben 3 Kinder, 2 sind depressiv, eins ist fröhlich. Das Fröhliche lacht." - "Meine Frau, ihre Schwester, deren Mann und ich spielen Mensch-ärgere-Dich-nicht. Der Verlierer zahlt eine Runde." Generisches Maskulinum - es kann auch eine Frau der Verlierer werden. Ähnlich mit dem Letzten, der die Tür zu macht. Solche Sätze werden absichtlich misverstanden, ...

Comment: ... aus einer politischen Mission heraus, gepaart mit einem naiven Sprachverständnis, welches sich weigert die Fakten wahrzunehmen, um an kruden Verschwörungstheorien festzuhalten. "Der Kügere gibt nach" - Du hast noch eine Chance. :)

Comment: @userunknown: Oh, jetzt weiß ich, worin dein Denkfehler besteht. In deinem Beispiel *»Wir haben 3 Kinder, 2 sind depressiv, eins ist fröhlich. Das **f**röhliche lacht.«* ist *»fröhliche«* kein substantiviertes Adjektiv, sondern ein ganz normales kleinzuschreibendes Adjektiv. Das Wort, worauf sich dieses Attribut bezieht, ist ja im Text vorhanden. Siehe §58 auf Seite 64 im [amtlichen Regelwerk](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf).

Comment: Zwei Beispiele aus diesem Dokument: Das erste Beispiel zeigt, das eine Übereinstimmung im Numerus nicht notwendig ist: *»Zwei Männer betraten den Raum; der **e**rste trug einen Anzug, ...«* Das nächste amtliche Beispiel zeigt, dass das Nomen, dessen Attribut das Adjektiv ist, auch in einem anderen Satz stehen darf: *»Der Verkäufer zeigte mir seine Auswahl an Krawatten. Die **g**estreiften und **g**epunkteten gefielen mir am besten.«*

Comment: Was das generische Maskulinum betrifft: Daran scheiden sich die Geister. Das ist keine grammatikalische, sondern eine gesellschaftspolitische Diskussion, und die möchte ich hier eigentlich nicht führen.

Comment: Das ist eine so sinnvolle Aussage wie die, ob der Mensch auf Evolution oder Schöpfung zurückginge sei keine biologische, sondern eine gesellschaftspolitische Diskussion. Man hat sich damit für die Seite des Kontrafaktischen, der schlechten Ideologie, entschieden. Damit stelle ich nicht in Abrede, dass die Entscheidung für die Fakten nicht auch gesellschaftspolitisch ist. Aber hier geht es um deutsche Sprache und nicht um politische Strategie und Agitation.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Entscheidung zwischen Evolution und Schöpfung betrifft etwas, das in der Vergangenheit geschehen ist, und das kann durch wissenschaftliche Methoden klar entschieden werden, wobei es hier natürlich Leute gibt, die wissenschaftliche Methoden nicht anerkennen. Die Entscheidung, wie bestimmte Eigenschaften einer lebenden, und sich somit ständig verändernden Sprache zu interpretieren sind, ist vergleichbar mit der Frage, ob sich bestimmte musikalische Akkorde eignen, in Musikstücken verwendet zu werden. ...

Comment: ... Was in der Barockmusik noch streng verboten war, kann in der Zwölftonmusik geradezu Pflicht sein. Die Bedeutung des generischen Maskulinums wandelt sich gerade, und zwar durch gesellschaftspolitische Ereignisse, und das hat Einfluss auf die Sprache. Die Sprache wurde immer schon auf vielfältige Weise verändert, und jetzt ist das nicht anders. Man kann sich dagegen wehren (»Das haben wir schon immer so gemacht«; »Das haben wir noch nie so gemacht«; »Da könnte ja jeder kommen«) oder man kann akzeptieren, dass sich die Welt verändert. Aber aufhalten kann man den Wandel nicht.

Comment: Ein von Autoritäten verordneter Sprachgebrauch ist m.E. noch kein Wandel, nur weil sich ein paar öffentliche Anstalten danach richten. Weder in Zeitungen, noch in der Literatur hat diese Bewegung mehr als kleine, organisierte Gruppen erfasst, von mündlicher Sprache, in der diese Bürokratismen ihre ganze Sperrigkeit entfalten, gar nicht zu reden. Der Musikvergleich ist Humbug, weil die Propagandisten gerechter Sprache falsche Behauptungen über die Sprache, wie sie war und weitgehend noch ist als Basis für ihre Änderungsansprüche formulieren.

Comment: Was aus dem Theoretisieren, ausgehend von falschen Prämissen, folgt, muss ich Dir glaube ich nicht erklären. Wenn man den Hebel an der falschen Stelle ansetzt bricht der Hebel ab.

Comment: Wie bereits weiter oben gesagt: Das ist eine gesellschaftspolitische Diskussion, und die möchte ich hier eigentlich nicht führen.

Answer (score 3):

It's one of those German words which comes in all three flavors.

> Der/die/das Weise – the wise man/woman/thing

This is because it's made from the adjective *weise*, and nouns made from adjectives always have all three genders.

And then there's

> Die Weise – the manner; the sage; the tune

Comment: Wenn sich jemand schon die Mühe macht, auf Deutsch zu fragen, sollte man dann nicht vielleicht auch so nett sein und in derselben Sprache antworten?

Comment: Er hat sich untendrunter auf Englisch für sein schlechtes Deutsch entschuldigt, was jemand (vermutlich du selbst) herauseditiert hat. Wenn jemand so etwas schreibt, antworte ich aus Gründen der Verständlichkeit natürlich in einer Sprache, die derjenige vermeintlich besser versteht. Im übrigen halte ich es für eine clowneske Frechheit, die Frage zu editieren und dann über Antworten auf die Originalfrage zu meckern.

Answer (score 0):

"Weise" in German translates into "wise" in English. This in turn, has multiple meanings in both languages, that have multiple genders in German. So your question should be, "Was *sind* die korrekten Geschlechter des Wortes »Weise«?"

Der Weise means the "wise" (person). This could be a man or woman, but would be treated as masculine in German. "A word to the wise. Ein (Sprich)Wort für der Weise.

"-wise" could also be translated as "manner," or "way." As in "I don't know what your point is, "language*wise*." The noun, "in the language way," would be translated as die Gesprächweise, feminine.